# How to properly use the core drill ability of DWAARP?

Tags: kingdom-rush, kingdom-rush-frontiers

One ability that I never buy on the DWAARP tower is the core drill, because it seems to gets wasted on weak enemies. How does the AI work here? Does it instakill the strongest enemy or the enemy closest to the exit? What is a cost-effective usecase for that skill?